# How to .pop() a specific item on a 2D list?

Tags: python, list

How to `.pop()` a specific item on a 2D list?
Let's say I have the list:

```
fruit_list = [['tomato', 'pineapple', 'mango'], ['cherry', 'orange', 'strawberry']]
```

If I `.pop()` `fruit_list` it would return `['cherry', 'orange', 'strawberry']`, because that is the last item of list but is there a way in Python to just pop `'mango'`, the last item of an inner list?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
item = fruit_list[0].pop()
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> fruit_list = [['tomato', 'pineapple', 'mango'], ['cherry', 'orange', 'strawberry']]
>>> fruit_list[0]
['tomato', 'pineapple', 'mango']
>>> fruit_list[0].pop()
'mango'
>>> fruit_list
[['tomato', 'pineapple'], ['cherry', 'orange', 'strawberry']]
>>>
```

Notice how you first index `fruit_list` at `0` to get the inner list.  Then, you call `.pop` on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.pop()` on the inner list then:

```
fruit_list[0].pop()
```

Your outer `fruit_list` contains more list objects. If you want to pop an item from one of *those* lists, call `.pop()` directly on such a list.

A quick demo:

```
>>> fruit_list = [['tomato', 'pineapple', 'mango'], ['cherry', 'orange', 'strawberry']]
>>> fruit_list[0]
['tomato', 'pineapple', 'mango']
>>> fruit_list[0].pop()
'mango'
>>> fruit_list
[['tomato', 'pineapple'], ['cherry', 'orange', 'strawberry']]
```